# PHP - why I couldn't declare static const variable?

Tags: php, oop

I would use them to implement `factory` pattern, for example:

```
class Types{
   static const car = "CarClass";
   static const tree = "TreeClass";
   static const cat = "CatClass";
   static const deathstar = "DeathStarClass";
}
```

And I would like to use them like:

```
$x = new Types::car;
```

Is it possible?

And what if my class has parametr in construcor, that doesn't work:

```
$x = new Types::car(123);
```

Comment: You mean, a static constant as opposed to a dynamic constant? :)

Comment: @John I still don't understand your example. Why do you declare the same constant four times? What would be the expected result? The `const` keyword as such should work, just leave off the `static`. It doesn't make sense for a constant.

Comment: There are no more 4 times the same, sry typo...

Comment: That's not the factory pattern...  If you're talking about a single class tree, [factory method](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) may work, or if your talking about a series of classes a [abstract factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) would work better.  But what you're doing is not an actual pattern (although it tries to solve the same problem)...

Comment: Are you sure this will work?  I just tried `$foo = new Foo::bar;`, and got a fatal syntax error...  So either way it prob won't work how you want it to...

Comment: @ircmaxell: See my comment on Sarfraz's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
class Types{
   const car = "CarClass";
   const tree = "TreeClass";
   const cat = "CatClass";
   const deathstar = "DeathStarClass";
}
```

Note that since constants are tied to the class definition, they are static by definition.

**From Docs:**

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to
>   reference the class using a variable.
>   The variable's value can not be a
>   keyword (e.g. self, parent and
>   static).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

**More Info:**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: OOO, exacly! That i would like achieve! But what if my class has smth in construcotr? I can't do it like: `$x = new Types::car(123);` ... :(

Comment: @John: Instantiate a variable class by assigning the constant value to a variable first: `$type = Types::car; $x = new $type(123);`

Comment: The only thing I would add is that naming convention for constants is all caps

Answer (score 4):

Constants are already static in the sense that they aren't tied to an instance of the class. Here is how to define them and use them as you want:

```
class Types{
   const car = "CarClass";
   const tree = "TreeClass";
   const cat = "CatClass";
   const deathstar = "DeathStarClass";
}

$x = Types::car;
```

Comment: You mean `Types::car`. Other than that, +1

Answer (score 1):

It's a constant.  You can't change it.  So it doesn't make any sense that you'd have a non-static constant member.  So you don't have to declare them as static or class variables.